# Encryption of text works for lower case only, upper case letters are unchanged

Tags: c

I am working on a pset and I need some help. The purpose of the program is to take a command line argument and use it as a key to encrypt some plaintext entered by the user and to shift it by the number of letters given. The uppercase letters should stay upper case, lower - lower. All other symbols should remain unchanged. My code encrypts only the lower case letters but not the upper case.
Please help me to figure out why.

```
 void encryption(string plaintext, int k, string ciphertext);
    int main(int argc, string argv[])
    {
        string plaintext;
        int n = strlen(plaintext);
        char ciphertext[n+1]; //the lenght of the plaintext+ 1 extra char which i
        int k = atoi(argv[1]); //Convert string into an integer, i.e parsing
    
    
        if (argc != 2)
        {
           printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
    
     
            for (int i = 0, m = strlen(argv[1]); i < m; i++)
        {
        if (isdigit(argv[1][i]))
          {
     plaintext = get_string("Plaintext:");
     encryption(plaintext, k, ciphertext); //calling the encryption function
       printf("Ciphertext: %s\n", ciphertext);
       return 0;
    
          }
    
       else
       {
          printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
       }
    
            }
        }
    }
    void encryption(string plaintext, int k, string ciphertext)
    {
    
        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(plaintext); i < n; i++)
        {
            if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
            {
                int  pi = plaintext[i] - 65;
                char ci = ((pi + k) % 26) + 65;
                ciphertext[i] = ci;
            }
    
            if (islower(plaintext[i]))
            {
                int pi1 = plaintext[i] - 97;
                char ci1 = ((pi1 + k) % 26) + 97;
                ciphertext[i] = ci1;
            }
            else
            {
                ciphertext[i] = plaintext[i];
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Here: `else { ciphertext[i] = plaintext[i]; }` where you changed it back to plain text. The above test `if (islower(plaintext[i]))` should be `else if (islower(plaintext[i]))`. I think you meant: **if** it's uppercase, **else** if it's lowercase, **else** plain.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now.

Comment: Consider naming functions using verbs, not nouns.  Functions _do_ things, and in language we describe that with a verb.  If you keep some kind of consistency with ordinary language in your program, it becomes easier to read and understand.  Particularly as the code grows in complexity.

Comment: Thank you, Paddy. I will do so from now on.